# Image of general divisor is smooth?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a proper, generically finite morphism between smooth, projective varieties. Let $\mathfrak{d}$ be a very ample linear system on $X$. Does the general member of $\mathfrak{d}$ have a smooth image under $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true.

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^3$ be the hypersurface
$$
X = \{((u_0:u_1),(x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3)) \mid u_0^2x_1 + u_0u_1x_2 + u_1^2x_3 = 0 \}.
$$
The projection to $\mathbb{P}^1$ is a $\mathbb{P}^2$-bundle, hence $X$ is smooth.
Let $Y = \mathbb{P}^3$ and $f \colon X \to Y$ is the natural projection. It is generically of degree 2, but has one fiber of positive dimension:
$$
C := f^{-1}(1:0:0:0) = \mathbb{P}^1.
$$
Consequently, any divisor cut out on $X$ by a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^4$ of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{P}^4$ intersects $C$ twice, hence its image in $Y$ has a double point at $(1:0:0:0)$.

Comment: Thanks, Sasha. Is there an example with $f$ finite?

Comment: I think so. For instance, take $X$ to be an abelian surface and $f \colon X \to Y = X/\tau$ factorization by  a point of order 2. Let $D \subset X$ be an ample divisor. Then $D \cdot \tau(D) > 0$ (since $D$ is ample), hence the image of $D$ in $Y$ has a point of self-intersection.